# Why is fill not working in my ggplot in my shiny app?

Tags: ggplot2, shiny, shinydashboard

I'm trying to replicate the following code into my shiny app:

```
df1 <- df %>% 
  group_by(xyz, inception_month) %>% 
  summarise(policies = sum(policies))

a <- ggplot(df1, aes(x=as.factor(inception_month), y = policies,  fill = xyz)) +
  geom_bar(position = "fill", stat = "identity") + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 30, hjust = 1)) +
  xlab("Inception Month") +
  ylab("Policy Count")
print(a)
```

which gives me the following desired output:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KOCc.png)

However I can't get the fill to display with the following dynamic code:

```
server <- function(input, output) {

df1 <- reactive({df %>% group_by(input$rating_factor, inception_month) %>% summarise(policies = sum(policies))})

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    p <- ggplot(data = df1(), aes(x=as.factor(inception_month), y = policies, fill = input$rating_factor)) +
      geom_bar(position = "fill", stat = "identity") +
    theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 30, hjust = 1)) +
      xlab("Inception Month") +
      ylab("Policy Count")

    print(p)
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

df looks like:

```
df <- data.frame(
  xyz = c("A","A","B","B","B"),
  abc = c("X","X","Y","Y","Y"),
  inception_month = c("Feb 2020", "Nov 2019", "Feb 2020", "Dec 2019", "Feb 2020"),
  policies = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 1))
```

and the ui is:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
    box(plotOutput("plot", height = 250)),

    box(
      title = "Select Rating Factor",
      selectInput("rating_factor", "Rating Factor", c("xyz", "abc"))
  )
  )
))
```

Comment: Hello, Antzlck. Welcome to StackOverflow. The example you posted isn't reproducible. We don't know what "df1" is made of. We have no access to "df". To improve your chances of getting a reply, you should either share the data in some way along with your code, or better, generate some fake data and make sure the column names in the fake data match the ones from your code. In R, the reprex package is great if you want to create a reproducible example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`input$rating_factor` creates a character value, which is not what `ggplot` expects. You need to use `!!sym(input$rating_factor)` instead.

I agree with Mason Beau's comment, though. Next time, you should provide a reproducible example. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) to know how to make one.

**Edit:** As detailed [here](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/programming.html), you have to use `!!sym()` in all `dplyr` functions as well. Here's your corrected example:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(
  xyz = c("A","A","B","B","B"),
  abc = c("X","X","Y","Y","Y"),
  inception_month = c("Feb 2020", "Nov 2019", "Feb 2020", "Dec 2019", "Feb 2020"),
  policies = c(1, 0, 1, 1, 1))

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(),
  dashboardSidebar(),
  dashboardBody(
    fluidRow(
      box(plotOutput("plot", height = 250)),

      box(
        title = "Select Rating Factor",
        selectInput("rating_factor", "Rating Factor", c("xyz", "abc"))
      )
    )
  ))

server <- function(input, output) {

  df1 <- reactive({
    df %>% 
      group_by(!!sym(input$rating_factor), inception_month) %>% 
      summarise(policies = sum(policies))
  })

  output$plot <- renderPlot({
    p <- ggplot(data = df1(), aes(x=as.factor(inception_month), y = policies, fill = !!sym(input$rating_factor))) +
      geom_bar(position = "fill", stat = "identity") +
      theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 30, hjust = 1)) +
      xlab("Inception Month") +
      ylab("Policy Count")

    print(p)
  })

}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Thanks.  I've tried that, but I get the error `object 'xyz' not found`

Comment: @Antzlck you need to make this change in all `dplyr` functions, like `group_by` in your example. I edited my answer

Comment: Thank you so much!